# Assigning ajax call return value to an var with jquery

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, global-variables

How can I assign a variable(var) to a json object which is returned from ajax call to the server? I need to access that object in the rest of the body.

For example, I've try this, I don't know it's correct.

```
var selectValues=$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "http://10.0.2.2/mobileajax/callajax.php",
                  data: ({name: theName}),
                  cache: false,
                  dataType: "text",
                  success: onSuccess
                });
})


var $vendor = $('select.mobile-vendor');
var $model = $('select.model');
$vendor.change(
              function() {
                  $model.empty().append(function() {
                      var output = '';
                      $.each(selectValues[$vendor.val()], function(key, value) {
                          output += '<option>' + key + '</option>';
                      });
                      return output;
                  });
              }).change();

// bonus: how to access the download link
$model.change(function() {
    $('a#download-link').attr('href', selectValues[$vendor.val()][$model.val()]).show();
});
```

Note that, variable `selectValues` is used in the rest of the body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should do the whole code inside the `$(document).ready(function()` function and then make the ajax call synchronous. Because now the ajax call will be made when the document is ready, but the other code will be run directly without waiting for the document to be ready. Also the ajax call is asynchronous by default, so you should make it synchronous and assign the `selectValues` variable inside the success function of the ajax call. It will become something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var selectValues;
        $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "http://10.0.2.2/mobileajax/callajax.php",
              data: ({name: theName}),
              cache: false,
              dataType: "text",
              async: false,
              success: function(data) {
                selectValues = data
              }
            });

            var $vendor = $('select.mobile-vendor');
            var $model = $('select.model');
            $vendor.change(
                          function() {
                              $model.empty().append(function() {
                                  var output = '';
                                  $.each(selectValues[$vendor.val()], function(key, value) {
                                      output += '<option>' + key + '</option>';
                                  });
                                  return output;
                              });
                          }).change();

            // bonus: how to access the download link
            $model.change(function() {
                $('a#download-link').attr('href', selectValues[$vendor.val()][$model.val()]).show();
            });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to define the var outside the `document ready` scope like this:

```
var selectValues;
$(document).ready(function() {
    // ajax
});
```

in the onSuccess function you can define the `selectValues = data` or something like that

Comment: assigning data to `selectValues`? I need to assign the returned value, not the sending value.

Comment: excuse me, i meant the `response` so something like `success: function(response) { selectValues = response; }`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response!

Comment: as long as the rest of your code isn't in the document ready this can't work .. because the rest of the code will be executed before the selectedValues is assigned.

Comment: true, but it's only triggered by `change` events :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "http://10.0.2.2/mobileajax/callajax.php",
              data: ({name: theName}),
              cache: false,
              dataType: "text",
              success: function (result){
                  var selectValues=result;
              }
            });
```

try this.

Comment: `var selectValues` will be only available in the `success` function and not outside that scope

Comment: Then define the "var selectValues" as global

Comment: indeed, that should be your answer to Kugathasan Abimaran

Comment: Even if `selectValues` is global, note that the rest of the page can't actually access the values until after the success callback runs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how we extract the returned information from our (xml) ajax calls:

```
$.ajax ({
    type: "POST",
    url: "something.cgi?someparam=whatever",
    data: "key=val&key2=val2",
    dataType: "xml", // you use json, but I don't think it matters
    success: function (data) {
    if ($("error", data).text() === "") {
        // I could assign $("error", data).text() to a var just here
        // This gets the "error" parameter out of the returned xml or
        // json, here contained in "data"
    }
    [snip the rest]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is to add the rest of your code in the success callback lik this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "http://10.0.2.2/mobileajax/callajax.php",
              data: ({name: theName}),
              cache: false,
              dataType: "text",
              async: false,
              success: function(selectValues) {
                var $vendor = $('select.mobile-vendor');
                var $model = $('select.model');
                $vendor.change(
                              function() {
                                  $model.empty().append(function() {
                                      var output = '';
                                      $.each(selectValues[$vendor.val()], function(key, value) {
                                          output += '<option>' + key + '</option>';
                                      });
                                      return output;
                                  });
                              }).change();

                // bonus: how to access the download link
                $model.change(function() {
                    $('a#download-link').attr('href', selectValues[$vendor.val()][$model.val()]).show();
                });
              }
            });

})
```